# How to get ramdom number between 1 and 2048 from /dev/hwrng?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

I am (perhaps naively) evaluating the security considerations of using the following code to create BIP39 seed phrases (on a read-only and offline Raspberry Pi).

Apparently, using `jot -r 1 1 2048` is not ideal and I would like to leverage the HRNG (`/dev/hwrng`) on Raspberry Pi hardware.

```
printf "%s\n" "Create random 24-word BIP39 seed phrase…"
seed=()
for i in $(seq 1 24); do
  seed+=($(sed "$(jot -r 1 1 2048)q;d" "/path/to/bip39.txt"))
done
echo ${seed[@]}
```

```
$ cat bip39.txt | head     
abandon
ability
able
about
above
absent
absorb
abstract
absurd
abuse
```

**Edit:** this approach would not work given BIP39 seeds use last word as a checksum (see [spec](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#Generating_the_mnemonic)).

Comment: Jot uses arc4random and see [Is `arc4random` secure enough?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/85601/86735) from infosec. Stick to `/dev/urandom`

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka. According to `man jot`, when a seed is provided, `random` is used vs `arc4random`. Given the seed has enough entropy, that would make randomness more cryptographically secure right?

Comment: If you believe the marketing hype/NSA/your state of mind, RPis have an embedded TRNG based around a secret implementation. https://scruss.com/blog/2013/06/07/well-that-was-unexpected-the-raspberry-pis-hardware-random-number-generator/

Comment: @kelalaka What command would you suggest to generate a cryptographically secure integer between 1 and 2048 (actually 24 of them)?

Comment: @PaulUszak Reading the story... would you happen to know how to get 24 random numbers between 1 and 2048 from `/dev/hwrng`?

Comment: @PaulUszak If the NSA controls your hardware, it doesn't matter whether you use its random generator or not. They'll know what you did anyway. Trusting everything on the platform except its random generator is silly.

Comment: This question is mostly off-topic since it's about a specific tool (`jot`) and a specific (unspecified) operating system. I've focused my answer on the on-topic part, which is "how do I read documentation to figure out whether a random generator is secure". For future reference, a site such as [unix.se], where Unix scripting tools is on-topic (easily determined from the site description) and security-related answers are usually good (not easily determined, but I claim that it's generally good – much better than [so] or [su]).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I beg to differ and you know that I'm right :-)  Of course _They_ don't control it. But computational indistinguishability means that we can test/validate all parts of the RPi, _other_ than it's supposed TRNG. That cannot be validated. It could be simply $\text{E}_{k  \oplus  id} (x)$. It probably isn't , but then, you can't prove that. [Null Gamma](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/nullgamma/) is based on this principle (using an RPi).

Comment: @PaulUszak It really wouldn't be that hard to reverse engineer their TRNG implementation. I actually wouldn't be too surprised if it was done already. The NSA would have to go full retard to put such a backdoor in a RPi given how easy it is to photograph the die.

Comment: Read octets One and Two from `/dev/hwrng`. Number = (One << 3) ^ Two + 1 where all variables are at least 16 bits. Don't trust your life on it though. _They're_ listening!

Comment: @forest We would appreciate your input re: [Can any part of Intel's (RdRand) random number generator be visually inspected?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/311438/56469)

Comment: @PaulUszak Decapping and inspecting the die of an embedded ARM processor is orders of magnitude easier than doing it for a large x86 chipset. Not to mention, Intel is much more likely to use anti-reverse engineering techniques than Broadcom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different versions of `jot`, and they use different sources of randomness. The [Debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/random.3.en.html) states:

> Random numbers are obtained through [`random(3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/random.3.en.html).

> s defaults to a seed depending upon the time of day

`random` is not cryptographically secure. This is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, so it's a good guess that it isn't¹. Even if it was, The seed being the time of day is very predictable. So `jot` on Debian is not at all suitable to generate a key or anything else that needs to be secure.

The [OpenBSD man page](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.8/jot.1) states:

> Random numbers are obtained through [`arc4random(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.8/arc4random.3). Historical versions of jot used s to seed the random number generator. This is no longer supported.

`arc4random` on OpenBSD is secure, as documented in the man page². So on OpenBSD, your script generates a passphrase securely, with $24 \log_2(n)$ bits of entropy where $n$ is the length of the word lists (assuming the word lists has no duplicates).

---

If you have GNU utilities, use [`shuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html#shuf-invocation). It can be instructed to use secure randomness:

> `--random-source=file`
> Use `file` as a source of random data used to determine which permutation to generate. See [Random sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources).

> By default these commands use an internal pseudo-random generator initialized by a small amount of entropy, but can be directed to use an external source with the `--random-source=file` option. (…) The set of available sources depends on your operating system.

On Linux, [`/dev/urandom` is secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key) except on a freshly installed system that doesn't have a hardware random generator. Since your platform has a hardware random generator, you don't need to worry about the initial seeding of the system random generator.

So with GNU coreutils, your script can just be

```
shuf --random-source=/dev/urandom -r -n 24 <bip39.txt
```

¹<sub>I confirm that guess.</sub>
² <sub>Historically, `arc4random` used [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), which is now [broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Biased_outputs_of_the_RC4). The output is biased, which would reduce the entropy of the resulting key, but not enough to break it. In any case OpenBSD switched to a different algorithm (currently ChaCha20), so `arc4random` is safe. Other modern BSD variants have switched `arc4random` to be secure as well, but beware that older releases of FreeBSD and NetBSD were insecure.</sub>.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your knowledge! Very insightful!

Comment: _it's possible to reconstruct the seed (and therefore the whole output) given enough partial output_ – RC4 is horrible, but this is **simply not true**. The main problem is that the keystream has severe biases. The only way to reconstruct the seed is if you have multiple keystreams encrypted with multiple keys that differ only in a few bits (think WEP with its fixed key and 24-bit random IV). But there is no known way to compute the RC4 state array given only the keystream, no matter how much of it you get.

Comment: @forest Thanks, I'd misremembered the recent improvements to RC4 cryptanalysis.